# Laravel Blade Sum function not counting negative numbers

Tags: php, laravel

My website has submissions, and those submissions have votes.

Upvotes are stored in the SubmissionVotes table as a tinyint in the column "vote" as `1`, and downvotes are stored as `-1`.

In my `Submission.php` model, there is a hasMany relationship to the vote model.

```
public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubmissionVote', 'vote');
}
```

In my blade template, I calculate the sum of these votes:

```
{{ $submission->votes->sum('vote') }}
```

Now this works fine if there's only upvotes. Three upvotes will return a score of 3.

But given a 3 downvotes and 3 upvotes, the sum should return 0 However, it returns 3.

In other words, it counts -1 as 0.

**Edit:**

Strange development. When I view what `$submission->votes` returns, it only gives me the results with positive numbers.

For example:

> [{"id":13,"user_id":2,"submission_id":1,"vote":1},{"id":22,"user_id":3,"submission_id":1,"vote":1}]

but when I view the database, I can see the negative votes as well:
[image]

Comment: If you try this: `collect([-1, 2, -2])->sum()` the result is -1 which is correct, so make sure that you have the values as you expect them. Check what does `$submission->votes` returns in your controller maybe, and see manually first if the result is what you expect.

Comment: Really strange! When I view `$submission->votes` it returns `[{"id":13,"user_id":2,"submission_id":1,"vote":1},{"id":22,"user_id":3,"submission_id":1,"vote":1}]` etc. but it's only returning the results with vote = 1 and not the results with vote = -1

Comment: and in your database you can see all the records? How do you query the records?

Comment: @nakov Yes. I edited the main post to reflect this

Comment: `vote` should not be the foreign key of the relationship. It probably works cause `$submission->id` would be 1, and it's returning all records where `vote` is 1. I think the answer below is saying the same thing.

Comment: @TimLewis Correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem might be here:

```
public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubmissionVote', 'vote');
}
```

`vote` is not a foreign key, it just happened to work for this two, because the vote is 1 and the submission is 1 I guess. But for negative number it won't work.

So instead of `vote` which cannot be a foreign key, you might want to change that to `submission_id` instead, so this:

```
public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\SubmissionVote', 'submission_id');
}
```

And in the SubmissionVote model you will have:

```
public function submission() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Submission');
}
```

Comment: "it just happened to work for this two, because the vote is 1 and the submission is 1" was exactly right. Thank you!